# How to increase persistently default storage of AZURE instance type via terraform?

Tags: azure, terraform-provider-azure

My use case to increase the default disk space of an AZURE VM (Linux) persitently and not ephemeral.
Those are the facts:

- created VM via terraform with instance type "Standard_D16s_v3", which
  has 32 GB disk space per default available
- I intend to increase/add 300 GB disk space

But I do not get it managed to attach a permanent disk to a Linux VM.
I tried with:

Creating a managed data-disk:

```
###managed storage disk creation for jumphost#####
resource "azurerm_managed_disk" "jump_disk" {
name = "jump_data1"
resource_group_name = "${var.resource_group_name}"
location = "${azurerm_resource_group.resource_group.location}"
storage_account_type = "Standard_LRS"
create_option = "Empty"
disk_size_gb = "300"
}
```

And attach later to LInux VM:

```
...
storage_os_disk {
name = "${var.resource_group_name}-osdisk"
caching = "ReadWrite"
create_option = "FromImage"
managed_disk_type = "Standard_LRS"
}

storage_data_disk {
name = "jump_data1"
managed_disk_id = "${azurerm_managed_disk.jump_disk.id}"
disk_size_gb = "300"
create_option = "Attach"
lun = 0
}
...
```

But getting on OS Level only /mnt/resource folder with information that data are ephemeral and will be lost after stopping/starting instance...and we shutdown&restart often to save costs:

```
[root@d021970-md300 ~]# df -h
Filesystem Size Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda2 32G 3.0G 29G 10% /
devtmpfs 63G 0 63G 0% /dev
tmpfs 63G 0 63G 0% /dev/shm
tmpfs 63G 9.1M 63G 1% /run
tmpfs 63G 0 63G 0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1 497M 101M 396M 21% /boot
/dev/sdb1 252G 2.1G 237G 1% /mnt/resource
tmpfs 13G 0 13G 0% /run/user/1000
[root@d021970-md300 ~]# cd /mnt/resource
[root@d021970-md300 resource]# ls
DATALOSS_WARNING_README.txt lost+found swapfile
[root@d021970-md300 resource]#
```

Does anybody know how to increase disk space not ephemeral, thus that after stopping and starting the VM all data is kept?

Thanks in advance.
Thomas

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide the `storage_service_name` or `media_link` parameters when creating the managed disk which will indicate that a new disk is to be created.

Not sure if LUN 0 should be used either as this would typically be the OS disk.  Try LUN 1.